# Solving Maze with Recursion java

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to find the path to the EndPosition. This is a recursive function. Please help, I'm about to kill myself.

This is the Map given

```
 { 1, 1, 1, 1 },
 { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
 { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
 { 0, 0, 1, 0 }};
```

I would like to use the GetPath recursively to get to the EndPosition in the map above. The parameters is the currentPosition, the end position and the map. For  this example, the starting position is (0,0) and ending and the EndPosition is (0,3), top right corner. 0's are for walls and 1's are for the path.

I need to return an arraylist filled with the valid points to the Ending Position. Though my array size is always 0 and the base case never returns the path. How can I keep track of the positions in an arraylist?

Please help, would appreciate it

```
  private ArrayList<Point> GetPath(Point CurrentPosition, Point EndPosition, int[][] Map)
    { 
    System.out.println("Current Position: " + CurrentPosition.toString());
    ArrayList<Point> p = new ArrayList<Point>();
    Path.add(CurrentPosition);

    if (CurrentPosition.equals(EndPosition))
    {

        return Path;
       }

        Map[(int)CurrentPosition.getX()][(int) CurrentPosition.getY()] = 0; //setting to 0 so my function wont revisit that position in the map 
ArrayList<Point> p2 = new ArrayList<Point>();    //Array for the 4 points around the CurrentPosition
        p2.add(new Point((int) CurrentPosition.getX(), (int) CurrentPosition.getY()+1));
        p2.add(new Point((int) CurrentPosition.getX()+1, (int) CurrentPosition.getY()));
        p2.add(new Point((int) CurrentPosition.getX(), (int) CurrentPosition.getY()-1));
        p2.add(new Point((int) CurrentPosition.getX()-1, (int) CurrentPosition.getY()));


    for (int i = 0; i < p2.size(); i++)
    {
        int j = 0;
        if (((p2.get(i).getX() >= 0 && p2.get(i).getY() >= 0) && (p2.get(i).getX() < Map.length && p2.get(i).getY() < Map[0].length)) && Map[(int) p2.get(i).getX()][(int) p2.get(i).getY()] !=0) //if the points in the array are within range and if the points aren't equal to 0.
        {
            Map[(int)p2.get(i).getX()][(int)p2.get(i).getY()] = 0; 
           GetPath(p2.get(i), EndPosition, Map); //recursive method

          }

        }

    return Path;
```

}

Comment: Similar question, you might wanna check it : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20187547/recursive-algorithm-for-2d-maze

Comment: doesn't seem like a for loop is necessary. Just pass in the new points as the updated current positions in your recursive call

Comment: Well the forloop are to access the 4 possible points in the array, if I dont use a forloop, how will I access all points?

Comment: @RoyKesserwani Well, seeing that you made those points individually one by one, you might as well have just made the recursive calls when you made those points.

Answer (score 2):

I think I may have found the problem:

You never do anything with the return value of your recursive call:

```
...
 Map[(int)p2.get(i).getX()][(int)p2.get(i).getY()] = 0; 
 GetPath(p2.get(i), EndPosition, Map); //recursive method
...
```

You should do the following:

```
ArrayList<Point> recPath = GetPath(p2.get(i), EndPosition, Map); //recursive method
Path.addAll(recPath);
```

You actually do need to `return Path` at the end after all

Comment: What is this actually returning?

Comment: It would return the path from your recursive call. So maybe you dont want to return it right away. Sorry, let me edit this

Answer (score 0):

create a function that takes as parameter the start and end position. have it scan every path it can for clear road. so if you can go north, west, south, east scan those locations for "1". if you find 1, have the function call itself again with the point where you found "1" as the new starting position. pass in the path so far and the targeted end position as well. once one of those finds a match for "1" at the given end position you have reached your path. this may not be optimal path. if you need that, parse all possible paths and pick shortest. in the end traverse your path backward to get all points. since the function gets as argument points visited so far, make sure you dont go to same point again by excluding those from future paths.

Comment: How can you traverse your path backwards?

Comment: well if you pass the previous point(s) as argument to your recursive function, you just reverse your recursion from that. if that previous point points to the previous point, you go back through those to the beginning.

Comment: give me an example please? I would appreciate it

Comment: the algorithm should be simple enough. also since you need to pass in the points visited on the path so far to avoid recursing the same path forever, you can just take that list when reaching the end point and that is your path.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<Point> getPath(Point start, Point end, int[][] Map)
{

    //Current Position for the currentPosition
    // EndPosition, given any point in the map would be the end of the maze
    // map is that map that given for example or any other map
    // returns an arraylist of positions of the paths
    ArrayList<Point> result = new ArrayList<Point>();
    boolean solutionExists = buildSolution(start, end, Map, result, new HashSet<Point>());
    return solutionExists? result : null;
}

public static boolean buildSolution(Point current, Point end, int[][] map, List<Point> solution, Set<Point> visited) {
    visited.add(current);
    if (current.equals(end)) {
        solution.add(current);
        return true;
    }
    if (map[current.x][current.y] == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    Set<Point> neighbours = getNeighbours(current, map);
    neighbours.removeAll(visited);
    for (Point neighbour : neighbours) {
        ArrayList<Point> temp = new ArrayList<Point>();
        Set<Point> tempVisited = new HashSet<Point>(visited);
        tempVisited.add(neighbour);
        if (buildSolution(neighbour, end, map, temp, tempVisited)) {
            solution.add(current);
            solution.addAll(temp);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static Set<Point> getNeighbours(Point current, int[][] map) {
    int maxX = map.length - 1;
    int maxY = map[0].length - 1;
    Set<Point> result = new HashSet<Point>();
    result.add(new Point(current.x, current.y - 1 < 0 ? current.y :current.y -1));
    result.add(new Point(current.x, current.y + 1 > maxY ? current.y : current.y +1));
    result.add(new Point(current.x - 1 < 0 ? current.x : current.x -1 , current.y));
    result.add(new Point(current.x + 1 > maxX ? current.x : current.x  + 1, current.y));
    result.remove(current);
    return result;
}
```